# C++ Program runs intermittently

Tags: c++, buffer, overflow, rounding

***Update***
I made some changes and it works now reliably. But from the comments, I see I did not use the correct methods. Here is the function and the only way I could find to make it work. Is this method incorrect?:

```
void findavgTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[], int quantum)
{
    //vector<int> wt(n);
    //vector<int> tat(n);
    int* wt = new int[n]; 
    int* tat = new int[n];
    int total_wt = 0;
    int total_tat = 0;

    findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt, quantum);
 
    findTurnAroundTime(processes, n, bt, wt, tat);

    cout << "Processes "  << " Burst time " << " Waiting time " << " Turn around time" << endl;
    //cout << *processes << *bt << wt << tat;
 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i];
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i];
        cout << " " << i+1 << "\t\t" << bt[i] <<"\t "
             << wt[i] <<"\t\t " << tat[i] <<endl;
    }
 
    cout << "Average waiting time = " << (float)total_wt / (float)n;
    cout << "\nAverage turn around time = " << (float)total_tat / (float)n;
}
```

---

I am struggling with getting my lab program running. Sometimes it runs ok usually it doesn't run correctly. It compiles, obviously, but there is a buffer overflow warning that I don't understand. My array rem_bt[] seems to be the culprit that is corrupting data. What am I missing? Running Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows 10 x64. Here's the code:

```
// C++ program for implementation of RR scheduling
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
// Function to find the waiting time for all
// processes
void findWaitingTime(int processes[], int n,
             int bt[], int wt[], int quantum)
{
    // Make a copy of burst times bt[] to store remaining
    // burst times.
    int* rem_bt = new int(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        rem_bt[i] = bt[i];
  
        int t = 0; // Current time
 
    // Keep traversing processes in round-robin manner
    // until all of them are not done.
    while (1)
    {
        bool done = true;
 
        // Traverse all processes one by one repeatedly
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        {
            // If burst time of a process is greater than 0
            // then only need to process further
            if (rem_bt[i] > 0)
            {
                done = false; // There is a pending process
 
                if (rem_bt[i] > quantum)
                {
                    // Increase the value of t i.e. shows
                    // how much time a process has been processed
                    t += quantum;
 
                    // Decrease the burst_time of current process
                    // by quantum
                    rem_bt[i] -= quantum;
                }
 
                // If burst time is smaller than or equal to
                // quantum. Last cycle for this process
                else
                {
                    // Increase the value of t i.e. shows
                    // how much time a process has been processed
                    t = t + rem_bt[i];
 
                    // Waiting time is current time minus time
                    // used by this process
                    wt[i] = t - bt[i];
 
                    // As the process gets fully executed
                    // make its remaining burst time = 0
                    rem_bt[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
 
        // If all processes are done
        if (done == true)
          break;
    }
}
 
// Function to calculate turn around time
void findTurnAroundTime(int processes[], int n,
                        int bt[], int wt[], int tat[])
{
    // calculating turnaround time by adding
    // bt[i] + wt[i]
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        tat[i] = bt[i] + wt[i];
}
 
// Function to calculate average time
void findavgTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[], int quantum)
{
    int* wt = new int(n); 
    int* tat = new int(n);
    wt[n];
    tat[n];
    int total_wt = 0;
    int total_tat = 0;
 
    // Function to find waiting time of all processes
    findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt, quantum);
 
    // Function to find turn around time for all processes
    findTurnAroundTime(processes, n, bt, wt, tat);
 
    // Display processes along with all details
    cout << "Processes "  << " Burst time " << " Waiting time " << " Turn around time" << endl;
    cout << processes << bt << wt << tat;
 
    // Calculate total waiting time and total turn
    // around time
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i];
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i];
        cout << " " << i+1 << "\t\t" << bt[i] <<"\t "
             << wt[i] <<"\t\t " << tat[i] <<endl;
    }
 
    cout << "Average waiting time = "
         << (float)total_wt / (float)n;
    cout << "\nAverage turn around time = "
         << (float)total_tat / (float)n;
}
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    // process id's
    int processes[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int n = sizeof processes / sizeof processes[0];
 
    // Burst time of all processes
    int burst_time[] = {10, 5, 8};
 
    // Time quantum
    int quantum = 2;
    findavgTime(processes, n, burst_time, quantum);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* rem_bt = new int(n);` allocates _one_ `int` with the value `n`. Why are you manually allocating memory? You leak everything you allocate. Replace that line with `std::vector<int> rem_bt(n);` to get rid of one of the problems. And this: `wt[n]; tat[n];` - what is that? _If_ you had allocated `n` elements (which you haven't) you'd been accessing the array out of bounds there

Comment: Your plan was to type `int* rem_bt = new int[n];`, so typo, but this bad very old pattern and you should just use `std::vector` as Ted points out.

Comment: Btw, it seems pointless to pass `processes` to functions that are not using it. [Updated](https://godbolt.org/z/8ccj9x17W)

Comment: @TedLyngmo -Thanks for the usage of vector. Regarding ```wt[n]; tat[n];``` doing this cleared a error. I used vector at the top of the program as you suggested and that took care of the errors up there. It does not apply to the section in which I reverted to the original code I am debugging. I get the error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant, that vector does not clear. Here's that code:
`
void findavgTime(int processes[], int n, int bt[], int quantum)
{
    int wt[n], tat[n], total_wt = 0, total_tat = 0;
`

Comment: @RyanDunnion There you have new errors. `int wt[n], tat[n]` is not valid C++. Those are called VLA:s (variable length arrays - because `n` is not a compile time constant) and are only available as an extension in some implementations (and VS2019 is not one of them). Don't use them even if you find an implementation that accepts them. Use `std::vector<int> wt(n), tat(n);` instead. Did you look at my suggested edit of the code? It replaces _all_ manual memory management with `vector<int>`s. No VLA:s and no leaks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I tried that, but now have this error: (93,50): error C2664: 'void findWaitingTime(int [],int,int [],int [],int)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>' to 'int []'

Comment: It's because you are not using the `vector`s like I showed [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8ccj9x17W).

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for that code. I am going over it after work.

Comment: @RyanDunnion You're welcome! I made [a final improvement](https://godbolt.org/z/KcrKxY8rj) to make it even easier to read and understand what goes into the functions and what comes out (by returning the result instead).